# Is sinx a piecewise monotonic function?

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

Well, sinx is not a monotonic function on R , but it is monotonic on subintervals ,like ,[0,π/2),[π/2,π),....
So based on this property can we say sinx is a piece wise monotonic function ?

Comment: You can say that, but if you look for functions that do not satisfy that definition, you'll see that it is of little use.

Comment: Is *sinx* supposed to be $\sin(x)$ ?

Comment: Yup! @Claude Leibovici